# Do a line and capsule intersect if mininum distance between the two lines is less than the capsule radius

Tags: geometry, parametric

In $R^3$ space say I have a capsule shape defined by two end points $a$ and $b$ and radius $r$. And a line define by parametric equation $p+tq$. I can also define a line that goes through the capsule end points $a+u(b-a)$

Is it true that the line $p+tq$ and the capsule intersect if the minimum distance between the two lines is less or equal to $r$?

If not how would one calculate if the two shapes intersect?

Comment: What precisely is a “capsule”?

Comment: @TedShifrin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_(geometry) not sure how to define it more specifically

Comment: OK, thanks. I had never encountered this before. To answer your question, the lines might intersect far away and have distance $0$. Minimum distance won’t help with your question.

Comment: @TedShifrin I had suspicions it was the case, thank you!

Comment: I like the definition "stadium of revolution" !!!

Comment: If you find a shortest segment, connecting these two lines, **and** its length will be less than $r$, **and** one of its ends will be inside the capsule "axis", then the line and the capsule intersect.

Comment: The capsule axis is the segment $[a,b]$. Two corner cases - the lines intersect, and they are parallel.